# Installing Rails on Mac OS X El Capitan v10.11.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError) Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/loofah-2.0.3.gemspec.rz)

^Keep getting the above. *Note* I'm in China and have tried both with/without VPN. Have also gone to https://ruby.taobao.org/ but do not know how to install this.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely the Great Firewall causes this. (See, e.g., [this issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1574).) Look at https://ruby.taobao.org/index_en.html for information in English on how to use ruby.taobao.org.